# SQL query to sum separate columns with separate Where conditions

Tags: sql

SQL noob here. I want to sum two columns separately, using 2 separate where conditions.

```
ID  NAME    VALUE1   VALUE2
--- ------- -------  -------
1   Orange  5        30
2   Orange  11       30
3   Orange  7        15 
4   Pear    12       12 
5   Pear    13       25 
6   Pear    4        25
```

- Sum of VALUE1 column where values are > 10
- Sum of VALUE2 column where values are > 20
- Grouped by NAME

Desired output:

```
NAME    VALUE1   VALUE2
------- -------  -------
Orange  11       60
Pear    25       50
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
select name, sum(case when value1 > 10 then value1 end),
       sum(case when value2 > 20 then value2 end)
from t
group by name;
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this approach is bit tricky and lengthy as well,however this might be helpful in debugging ,if you can try this :

```
select 
value1.name,value1.a,value2.b 
from 
(select sum(value1)a,name from test where value1 >10 group by name) as value1
join (select sum(value2)b,name from test where value2 >20 group by name) as value2
on value1.name = value2.name
```